# I need to transform an equation into another using taylor series

Tags: integration, derivatives, taylor-expansion, mathematical-astronomy

I have an astrophysics class and I am trying to finalize some exercices. My astrophysics teacher didn't teach us any of this saying that we should have learned it from other classes by other teachers (which I did not). I need to transform this equation

$$v+Δv=(v+Δv')/(1+(vΔv')/c^2)  \tag{1}$$

into this

$$Δv≈Δv'(1-v^2/c^2) \tag{2}$$

My instructions say that I should first transform the denominator of (1) into a Taylor series. Then I need to eleminate every (Δv’)^2 to obtain (2).
I have no clue how I am supposed to do so.
(1) is the velocity addition formula

Answer (score 1):

I think I got it, for future references heres what I did after using hamam's hint:      $$v+Δv≈(v+Δv')(1−(vΔv′)/c^2)  $$                                                   $$v+Δv≈v+Δv′-((vΔv'^2)/c^2)-((v^2Δv′)/c^2)  $$                                          $$Δv≈Δv′-(vΔv'^2)/c^2)-((v^2Δv′)/c^2) $$                                               $$Δv≈Δv′(1-(vΔv'/c^2)-(v^2/c^2)) $$   Using the fact that
$$v+Δv≈(v+Δv')(1−(vΔv′)/c^2)$$
I find that
$$(v+Δv)/(v+v′)≈ 1-(vΔv'/c^2)$$                                                   $$Δv≈Δv′((v+Δv)/(v+Δv')-(v^2/c^2))  $$  I then know that  $$ (v+Δv)/(v+v′)≈ 1$$ Which leaves me with                                              $$Δv≈Δv′(1-(v^2/c^2))  $$  P.S. if this is wrong please tell

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

If $ X$ is closer to zero, then

$$\frac{1}{1+X}=1-X+X^2-X^3+...$$
$$\approx 1-X$$

So

$$\frac{1}{1+\frac{v\Delta v'}{c^2}}\approx 1-\frac{v\Delta v'}{c^2}$$